# Arkham Horror LCD: having a card under control

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

I'm confused by what **control** is and refrence book doesn't quite clear it up. Let's take these two cards from Dunwich Legacy base box:

1. [All-in](https://arkhamdb.com/card/02068):
   on the *a-side* we have:

> While Dr. Morgan is not controlled by a player, he gains "... If there are 1 clues/investigator on Dr. Morgan, take control of him."

2. and on the *b-side*:

> If an investigator resigned with Dr. Francis Morgan under his or her control, (→R2)

3. [Dr. Francis Morgan card](https://arkhamdb.com/card/02080): an ally.

So how do I use these cards? If I succeed at the (3) test, can I place Dr. Morgan's card into my *hand* first or do I have to play it right away? What if I don't have enough resources or my in-play ally slot is already occupied?

Then, to satisfy b-side condition, will I have to put Morgan's card to my play area or does having it in my hand suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr. Morgan should go directly to your play area just like [Lita Chantler](https://arkhamdb.com/card/01117). Another example of cards you control would be [Cryptic Chill](https://arkhamdb.com/card/01167) where the rules state cards with abilities can only interact with cards that are in play. Inversely, a card you take in your control would also go to your in-play area unless otherwise specified.